# Flutter center() widget required parameter error

Tags: flutter

While attempting to use the Center() widget the VSCode throughs an error

> 1 required argument(s) expected, but 0 found.

This includes all flutter projects, including the default "hello world!" project.

The flutter version info:

```
PS D:\Flutter\Projects\test02> flutter --version
Flutter 1.0.0 • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 5391447fae (6 weeks ago) • 2018-11-29 19:41:26 -0800
Engine • revision 7375a0f414
Tools • Dart 2.1.0 (build 2.1.0-dev.9.4 f9ebf21297)
```

I googled the error, and many encountered the same error but with different widgets (card, MaterialApp, ...), and none of their solutions worked for me.

One of my attempts is to add null value, it removed the error but through a similar error during compilation.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white24,
      body: Center(null,
        child: ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("data"),
            Text("data"),
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Edit:

It turns out that I have modified the basic.dart file by mistake and added another parameter to the center class constructor.

I figured the issue while trying to change the channel to stable, I got an error telling me that I have uncommitted changes. This issue was solved by removing the extra parameter from the constructor.

Comment: try to run `flutter clean`

Comment: I already run it, but its the same

Comment: check import packages may there another center class

Comment: I only imported the material package. The default project "hello world" suffers from the same issue without any editing.

Answer (score 0):

On Center constructor, first argumento is Key and it cannot be null. Just remove `null` . https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Center-class.html

Comment: I think my center widget is different for some reason <code>Center(Column column, {Key key, double widthFactor, double heightFactor, Widget child })</code> instead of <code>Center({Key key, double widthFactor, double heightFactor, Widget child })</code>

Comment: Based on docs, center constructor is: `Center({Key key, double widthFactor, double heightFactor, Widget child })`

Comment: I saw that in the documentation as well. For some reason mine got an extra column parameter. I tried to google that class but got no results.

Comment: are you using master or dev channel from flutter repo ?